# store details in gidview on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my application I first need to have a button on clicking the button user should see a pop up with labels and text boxes and on clicking the add button which is in modal pop up the data should be added to grid view every thing is done, but if for the first time i enter the details of a person and i click on add button then they are added to gridview, again if i enter details of another person then the details that are in gridview for first person are disappered and in gridview the second person details are displayed.But it should display both the records.Also if i again run the application after some time then the added records are not displayed in gridview that means ***when i run the application after some time if i have added the records previously thay should be displayed in gridview along with button but only the button is displayed but not gridview*** how can i display the added records even i run the application any no of times.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Background
        {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .Popup
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 350px;
        }
        .lbl
        {
            font-size:16px;
            font-style:italic;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Fill Form in Popup" />

            <div style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px">  
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CellPadding="2"  
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">  
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />  
        <Columns>  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="FirstName" />  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText=" MiddleName" DataField="MiddleName" />  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText=" LastName" DataField="LastName" />  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Gender" DataField="Gender" />  
        </Columns>  
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />  
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />  
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />  
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />  
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />  
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />  
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />  
    </asp:GridView>  
    </div>  
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Button1"
    CancelControlID="Button2" BackgroundCssClass="Background">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" style = "display:none">
    <div id="irm1" style=" width: 300px; height: 250px;" runat="server" >
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Middle Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </div>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
    </form>
</body>
```

In my code behind-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("FirstName");
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("MiddleName");
            DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("LastName");
            DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Gender");
            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        DataTable dt;

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1[0] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr1[1] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr1[2] = TextBox3.Text;
            dr1[3] = TextBox4.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            ClearFields();

        }
        protected void ClearFields()
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            TextBox3.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I think you wanna use ascx not aspx, also It dones't say which code behind is this webform1 or webform2? you can't use webform2s elements in webform1's code behind from iframe. try to copy those codes to webform2s code behind.

Answer (score 0):

carry your gridview inside Panl1 and all your code behind to webform1.cs, delete webform2, you dont need it.

Comment: thats another problem, try to replace your popup mechanism with something popular like  one of these https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/modal/

Comment: cover the code in page load with  if(!IsPostback){//your code here}